# Swift UI and Unity contents integration on Vision Pro

Tags: swift, xcode, unity-game-engine, visionos, vision-pro

I plan to develop an App with Swift based UI (contents selector) and Unity based 3D contents.

Would it be possible to integrate Swift and Unity?
I think Unity as a service is not compatible with VisionOS.

I guess one possible option would be Swift app executes Unity app which is included Swift app.

If someone has any idea, please help us.

I tried to make Swift app and Unity app for Vision OS separately, but don't know how to integrate them.

Comment: If Unity as a library works with a VisionOS app, it will be perfect.

Comment: Is the Unity VisionOS preview out already? I thought we were still waiting:  https://create.unity.com/spatial